# I have created my own smtp server for sending email, But email is going in spam. KIndly guide me

Tags: mail-server

I have created my own smtp server for sending email using postfix. But all emails going in spam. How can i fix this. I have already added Dkim record, all other record and My ip is also not bocked

I have tried this using this link https://phoenixnap.com/kb/postfix-smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue a few months ago. If everything is good and verified. You just need to wait to build your reputation. I did just one thing sent emails to different email addresses daily. after some days my email started going to inbox.
**Note: This is the case if your spam tester gives you a 100 score.**
I have used this link to do spam-checking.
https://www.mail-tester.com